# Error when referencing Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC 4 solution. It works fine. If I try to add some links on top of the cshtml file like like below, my MVC solution breaks. All I see when clicking a link is the word "undefined".

What did I do wrong?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean clicking a link?

Answer (score 0):

And your positive that line is whats doing it? You have compiled and ran the solution without that line and its no problem?  That is a CSS file, it has nothing to do with jQuery on its own.. so my guess is you have some false positives going on in your head.  Verify each step and you might be suprised that it is something else that is your problem.

Can you post a screen of the error message, and a more detailed code sample?

It seems that even with your new code sample provided that this would be unrelated to the problem. You need to give us more information.  As another note you should probably also include script type="text/javascript".

Add to css link type="text/css" />

Add to javascript include type="text/javascript"

this might fix your problem but i doubt it, chances are its unrelated to these lines.

Comment: Thanks. I actually have 2 file: one in Shared and one in Home folder. The other one caused problem